# Error creating a spatial database using EXTENSIONS

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew, postgis, gdal

When running `psql -d mydb -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so": dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so, 10): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_column_table_name
      Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.1.dylib
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
     in /usr/local/lib/libgdal.1.dylib
STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

System: OS X 10.9.2
All libraries were installed with homebrew.

I tried reinstalling 'gdal', 'geos', 'postgresql', 'postgis' with homebrew without any luck. I'm suspecting it may be something related to sqlite3, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that it was using the sqlite3 library that is installed by default by OS X. After linking the brewed library using `brew link sqlite3 --force` I was able to create the postgis extension.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. My fix was :

```
brew link --overwrite jpeg
```

Hope this helps!