# Failing to load rgdal package in R

Tags: r, installation, rgdal

I'm having trouble loading rgdal in RStudio. I tried the usual command install.packages and when prompted with

> "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation (Yes/no/cancel)"

I've tried both yes and no. However I continue to get a cryptic error message when I try to load the library for use. It is:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = >DLLpath, ...):
>   unable to load shared object >'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_column_table_name
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>    in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666753/r-version-3-4-0-rgdal-will-not-load?rq=1

Comment: Actually this seems closer to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269978/error-creating-a-spatial-database-using-extensions

Comment: Have you found a solution?